# MySQL change date format from 'Thursday 5th of July 2018' to '2018-07-05'

Tags: mysql, date-format

everyday I get CSV file with orders. Problem is because column with date looks like 'Thursday 5th of July 2018' I want to import that CSV file to database and change date format to '2018-07-05'. It is possible?

Comment: It can be done using php. is this project built using php?

Comment: This should be done in your application layer if possible.

Comment: I've sorted it out in this way:
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Thursday 5th of July 2018', '%W %D of %M %Y') AS date;